# Regex in java for unstructured pincode

Tags: java, regex

I have a sample of texts on which i am trying to apply the regex , but unable to cover all the cases

Sample of texts :

```
311001
311 001
ds311001NM
ds311 001NM
asd,.;546798;l';
asd,.;546798;l';
asd,.; 546798;l';
asd,.; 546798 ;l';
asd,.; 546 798 ;l';
asd,.;546 798 ;l';
```

pin codes can have spaces in between or may not have . I tried with regex `[1-9]{3}\\s*[0-9]{3}` , but it does not cover all the cases, like `asd,.;506 798 ;l';`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So which cases aren't covered by this regex?

Comment: The concensus is that "give me a regex that does X" questions [should be closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed).

Comment: What is a pincode? What makes a pincode valid for you? Are all of your samples valid pincodes? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your question is comprehensible and answerable. Then, update and improve your *question*.

Comment: Instead of complex regex solution if you want simply  to have only numbers with spaces try . str.replaceAll("[^\\s0-9]", "");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have matches 3 digits from the `1-9` range so, it cannot find `200 345` type of PIN.

You need a simpler regex

```
\d{3}\s*\d{3}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ad4X4u/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/umcPwC):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("311001","311 001","ds311001NM","ds311 001NM","asd,.;546798;l';","asd,.;546798;l';","asd,.; 546798;l';","asd,.; 546798 ;l';","asd,.; 546 798 ;l';","asd,.;546 798 ;l';");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\s*\\d{3}");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the original [Regex works for the sample inputs](https://regex101.com/r/D3qH7q/1) and OP did not specify whether the first 3 digits may contain 0 or not.

Comment: There is only one potential issue with the regex, and I think it is the one I pointed out. I will remove the answer if OP states it is not the one.